# CardView in RecyclerView not clickable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My RecyclerVIew in Fragment

My Activity container:

My Fragment:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp" />
```

My CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp">

    ...

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The OnClickListener:

```
holder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("click","click");
    }
});
```

Why cardview is not clickable? What i do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is the `CardView` itself? I mean, with another view (a `FrameLayout` for example) does it work?

Comment: Are you setting the onClickListener correctly?

Comment: holder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("click","click");
            }
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RecyclerView differs a lot from a ListView. That means setting OnClickListener has to be done differently! Here is how I do mine.

**Step 1** - Create a class that you can reuse like this:

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

   private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
   private OnItemClickListener mListener;

   public interface OnItemClickListener {
      void onItemClick(View view, int position);
      void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);

   }

   public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener)
   {
       mListener = listener;

       mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
       {
         @Override
         public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
         {
             return true;
         }

         @Override
         public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e){
             View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

            if(childView != null && mListener != null){
                mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            }
         }
      });
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e)
    {
      View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

      if(childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
         mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
      }

      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {}

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
 }
```

Now that you have this class, you can simply attach the click listener to your RecyclerView inside your Fragment or Activity like this:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener
            .OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            //handle click events here
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            //handle longClick if any
        }
    }));
```

I hope this helps you because I have a feeling it is nothing to do with a CardView here! Good luck!